# Column of Binary Type -1 for MAX value

Tags: biml

I am building a VS solution and using BIML, I have created tiers and c# code files. 
When I run each individual biml file they compile and generate outputs in the viewer.
When I check for errors it throws up this error
"Column of binary type must specify positive Length or -1 to represent the MAX value.

In one of my c# code files I am doing a case statement on data type to switch into SQL data types.
In this code page I specify that the length of a binary column is -1 but I still getting the error.
Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried changing the -1 to 10 and also 1 but still get same error.

DataRow.cs FILE CONTENTS

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Varigence.Biml.Extensions;
    public static class DataRow
        {
        public static string GetBiml(this System.Data.DataRow dataRow)
        {
            StringBuilder biml = new StringBuilder("");

            biml.Append("<Column Name=\"")
                .Append(dataRow["ColumnName"])
                .Append("\" DataType=\"")
                .Append(dataRow["DataTypeBiml"])
                .Append("\"");

            if (dataRow["DataTypeBiml"].ToString().Contains("String"))
                biml.Append(" Length=\"").Append(dataRow["CharLength"]).Append("\"");
            else if (dataRow["DataTypeBiml"] == "Decimal")
                biml.Append(" Precision=\"").Append(dataRow["NumericPrecision"]).Append("\" Scale=\"").Append(dataRow["NumericScale"]).Append("\"");
            else if (dataRow["DataTypeBiml"] == "Binary")
                biml.Append(" Length=\"-1 \" ");

            if (dataRow["IsNullable"] != "NO")
                biml.Append(" IsNullable=\"true\"");
            else
                biml.Append(" IsNullable=\"false\"");

            biml.Append(" />");
            return biml.ToString();
        }
    }
```

1-ReadMetaData.biml

```
    <#@ template tier="10" #>
    <#@ import namespace="System.Data"#>
    <#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"#>

        <#@ code file="Helper.cs" #>
        <#@ code file="DataRow.cs" #>

    <#
        string targetConnection = @"Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Integrated Security=SSPI;"; 
    #>
    <Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
        <Tables>
            <#
                var sourceTables = Helper.GetIncludedSourceTablesList();

                // Loop through each source table in the included source tables list
                foreach (Table sourceTable in sourceTables) 
                {
            #>
            <Table Name="<#=sourceTable.Name#>" SchemaName="schema">
                <#
                    string targetQuery = @"SELECT OrdinalPosition = col.ORDINAL_POSITION,
                                                ColumnName = col.COLUMN_NAME,
                                                DataType = col.DATA_TYPE,
                                                CharLength = ISNULL(col.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, 0),
                                                NumericPrecision = col.NUMERIC_PRECISION,
                                                NumericScale = col.NUMERIC_SCALE,
                                                IsNullable = col.IS_NULLABLE,
                                                DataTypeBiml = CASE col.DATA_TYPE
                                                                WHEN 'bigint' THEN 'Int64'
                                                                WHEN 'bit' THEN 'Boolean'
                                                                WHEN 'char' THEN 'AnsiStringFixedLength'
                                                                WHEN 'datetime' THEN 'DateTime'
                                                                WHEN 'decimal' THEN 'Decimal'
                                                                WHEN 'float' THEN 'Double'
                                                                WHEN 'int' THEN 'Int32'
                                                                WHEN 'nchar' THEN 'StringFixedLength'
                                                                WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN 'String'
                                                                WHEN 'smallint' THEN 'Int16'
                                                                WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 'Binary'
                                                                WHEN 'tinyint' THEN 'Byte'
                                                                WHEN 'varchar' THEN 'AnsiString'
                                                                WHEN 'uniqueidentifier' THEN 'Guid'
                                                                ELSE 'Unknown'
                                                              END
                                            FROM (
                                                    SELECT lkup.TABLE_SCHEMA,
                                                        lkup.TABLE_NAME,
                                                        ORDINAL_POSITION_MAX = MAX(lkup.ORDINAL_POSITION)
                                                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS lkup
                                                    WHERE lkup.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
                                                            AND lkup.TABLE_NAME = '" + sourceTable.Name + @"'
                                                    GROUP BY lkup.TABLE_SCHEMA,
                                                    lkup.TABLE_NAME
                                                ) AS maxord
                                            INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS col ON (maxord.TABLE_SCHEMA = col.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                                                                            AND maxord.TABLE_NAME = col.TABLE_NAME)
                                            ORDER BY col.ORDINAL_POSITION;";


                    DataTable targetTable = new DataTable();
                    SqlDataAdapter targetAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(targetQuery,targetConnection);
                    targetAdapter.Fill(targetTable);
                #>
                <Columns>
                    <# foreach (DataRow targetRow in targetTable.Rows) {#>
                    <#=targetRow.GetBiml()#>
                    <# } #>
                </Columns>    
            </Table>
            <# } #>
        </Tables>
    </Biml>
```

TableList.cs FILE CONTENTS

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Varigence.Biml.Extensions;
    public class Helper
    {
        public static List<Table> GetIncludedSourceTablesList()
        {
            var tablesList = new List<Table>
            {
                new Table() { Name = "Tab1"},
                new Table() { Name = "Tab2" },
                new Table() { Name = "Tab3" },
                new Table() { Name = "Tab4" },
                new Table() { Name = "Tab5" },
                new Table() { Name = "Tab6" }
            };

            return tablesList;
        }
    }

    public class Table
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

this is the part of the output in the viewer of the ReadMetaData.biml file which is not putting the length against the binary column

```
    <Column Name="RowVers" DataType="Binary" IsNullable="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the mistake out, I Had not converted the DataTypeBiml to a string to compare it once I did the length was put out correctly.

```
else if (dataRow["DataTypeBiml"].ToString() == "Binary")
        biml.Append(" Length=\"-1\"");
```

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it may be as simple as that you have a trailing space after your `-1`, which could be discarding the `Length` property as it has an invalid value:

So this:

```
biml.Append(" Length=\"-1 \" ");
```

Should become this:

```
biml.Append(" Length=\"-1\" ");
```